# StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException occuring Frequently

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis, elastic-cache

we are using Elastic cache redis that aws provides in our .Net Core application and when we perform the below operation sometimes we are getting the below TimeoutException after sometime can someone please help me to solve this attaching exception for reference

_redis.KeyExists("cusID"+customerID) -> operation performed

Exception has occurred: CLR/StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException
Exception thrown: 'StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException' in StackExchange.Redis.dll: 'Timeout performing EXISTS (5000ms), next: EXISTS cusID1, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, serverEndpoint: master.test-stage-test-new-jayaram3.mvg9d6.aps1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: JAYA-397(SE.Redis-v2.5.61.22961), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=10000,Min=10000,Max=10000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=10000,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=13,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=790), v: 2.5.61.22961 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)'
at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl[T](Message message, ResultProcessor1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 1857 at StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync[T](Message message, ResultProcessor1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) in //src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisBase.cs:line 53
at StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.KeyExists(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags) in //src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisDatabase.cs:line 667

An exception of type 'StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException' occurred in StackExchange.Redis.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Timeout performing GET (5000ms), active: GET cusID1, next: GET cusID1 ** possible thread-theft indicated; see https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/ThreadTheft ** , inst: 1, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: SpinningDown, rs: CompletePendingMessageSync, ws: Idle, in: 0, serverEndpoint: master.suremdm-stage-test-new-jayaram3.mvg9d5.aps1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 8 of 10 available, clientName: JAYA-397(SE.Redis-v2.5.61.22961), IOCP: (Busy=3,Free=9997,Min=10000,Max=10000), WORKER: (Busy=5,Free=32762,Min=10000,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=12,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=2634), v: 2.5.61.22961 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)'

If need some more information, just ask me that I'll try to provide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked if you can reach (e.g. ping) the ElastiCache Redis instance? I would advise to double check your VPC settings, it might be that you're running into timeouts because the application is unable to reach the ElastiCache Redis instance.

Comment: This helped me, I did not have targetFramework in my httpRuntime tag in my web.config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/993854/all-redis-commands-timing-out-when-using-azure-cac.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting "AbortOnConnectFail" to false so it continues to try to reconnect? When a connection breaks (could be due to a failover etc), commands already sent to Redis on the now broken connection will timeout on the client.

Comment: No I was not using it Thanks for the advice I will add it to my connection string

Comment: still I'm getting timeouts

Comment: Do yoi get any solution?